# There have uncommitted changes, but `show | compare` do not show it

Tags: juniper

There have uncommitted changes, but `show | compare` do not show it.

```
{master}[edit]                                                                  
un@HK-MX-RE0# exit                                                          
The configuration has been changed but not committed                            
Exit with uncommitted changes? [yes,no] (yes) no                                

Exit aborted                                                                    

{master}[edit]                                                                  
un@HK-MX-RE0# show | compare                                                

{master}[edit]                                                                  
un@HK-MX-RE0#
```

My device is Juniper MX480.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one: `show | compare rollback 1`

Also this situation may rise in case when you change value(option), then in the same session revert this changed value to previous state. < This is my mention, not confirmed by the documentation.

Answer (score 3):

If there is no delta showing, just type `rollback` before `exit` and this error will go away.

Comment: What's the meaning of `If there is no delta showing`?

Comment: If like you say in your question, you run `show | compare` and there is no output, so no delta.  As Ivan said, sometimes just changing something then changing it back is enough to trigger Junos to think there is a diff

Comment: @244boy . Or can you just use rollback 0 and then you can exit out of configuration mode provided the output of 'show | compare' doesn't show you the difference. Rollback 0 will revert to last known good configuration before trying to add new configurations.